# Maximum update depth exceeded in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to resolve the below error but not able to find out the actual cause. I went through all the solutions which were posted related to similar error but none of them answers my question.

Can someone please help me out on this?

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
at invariant (react-dom.development.js:57)
at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:20921)
at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11596)
at Router.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:336)
at react-router.js:60
at listener (history.js:162)
at history.js:180
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.notifyListeners (history.js:179)
at setState (history.js:300)
at history.js:414
at Object.confirmTransitionTo (history.js:152)
at replace (history.js:397)
at Lifecycle.onMount (react-router.js:290)
at Lifecycle.componentDidMount (react-router.js:174)
at Lifecycle.componentDidMount (react-hot-loader.development.js:652)
at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:18115)
at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:19674)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:19898)
at react-dom.development.js:21446
at Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:255)
at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:21445)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21368)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:21273)
at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:21247)
at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:21102)
at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:20915)
at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:21610)
at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:21636)
at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:21704)
at ReactRoot.push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:22017)
at react-dom.development.js:22169
at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21492)
at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:22165)
at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:22240)
at render (index.js:11)
at Module../src/index.js (index.js:25)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at fn (bootstrap:149)
at Object.0 (helpers.js:20)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: your loop is going infinity, are you used setState function in render() function

Comment: Post your component code, like @KishanJaiswal said, you might call setState somewhere in render()

Comment: I tried debugging and found out the below code is causing the issue. 
  if(!isCurrentUser() && location.pathname != '/'){
      return ( <Redirect to={'/'}/> );
    }
Here, Redirect component is causing the above error

Answer (score 1):

Don't afraid to read the error message. In the first string React tries to give a hint.

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

1. Be careful with setState, maybe You tried to create a function that toggles the state am I right?
2. The problem may be in lifeCycles such as componentWillUpdate.

Look close at Your code and don't afraid to read the error messages or documantation.
Good luck :)

Comment: if(!isCurrentUser() && location.pathname != '/'){
      return ( <Redirect to={'/'}/> );
    }

 Redirect component is causing the error, trying to find out the exact cause. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you triggering an onclick event?
I got a similar error and i fixed it using arrow functions instead standard call

`<button type="button" onClick={() => this.example()}>test</button>`

Post your code please